# ext js change color, width, and copy sprite

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ext js having a hard time learning it. How can I change the color, width and be able to copy a drawing. I would like to be able to change the color of the free hand drawing, change the line width, and be able to select and copy the sprite or the drawing.

My code so far:

This is the View

```
Ext.define('SketchApp.view.main.Shapes', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainShapes',

requires: [
'Ext.draw.Component',
'SketchApp.view.main.ShapesDrawComponent'
],

layout: 'anchor',
width: 650,
style: {borderColor:'black', borderStyle:'solid'},

tbar: ['->', {
    text: 'Clear',
    handler: function () {
        // Remove all the sprites and redraw.
        var draw = Ext.getCmp('free-draw');
        draw.getSurface().removeAll(true);
        draw.renderFrame();
    }
}],

items: [{
    xtype: 'free-draw-component',
    id: 'free-draw',
    anchor: '100%',
    height: 500
}],

onAdded: function(container, pos, instanced) { 
    this.callParent([container, pos, instanced]); 
    container.setScrollable(false);
},

onRemoved: function(destroying) {
    this.ownerCt.setScrollable(true);
    this.callParent([destroying]);
}

});
```

This is the Component

```
Ext.define('SketchApp.view.main.ShapesDrawComponent', function () {

    function smoothList(points) {
        if (points.length < 3) {
            return ['M', points[0], points[1]];
        }

        var dx = [], dy = [], result = ['M'],
            i, ln = points.length;

        for (i = 0; i < ln; i += 2) {
            dx.push(points[i]);
            dy.push(points[i + 1]);
        }

        dx = Ext.draw.Draw.spline(dx);
        dy = Ext.draw.Draw.spline(dy);
        result.push(dx[0], dy[0], 'C');

        for (i = 1, ln = dx.length; i < ln; i++) {
            result.push(dx[i], dy[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    return {
        extend: 'Ext.draw.Container',
        xtype: 'free-draw-component',

        config: {
            background: 'white'
        },

        sprite: undefined,
        lastEventX: undefined,
        lastEventY: undefined,
        list: [],

        constructor: function () {
            var me = this;

            me.callParent(arguments);

            me.on({
                element: 'element',
                mousedown: 'onMouseDown',
                mousemove: 'onMouseMove',
                mouseup: 'onMouseUp',
                mouseleave: 'onMouseUp',
                scope: me
            });
        },

        onMouseDown: function (e) {
            var targetElement = this,
                me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id),
                surface = me.getSurface(),
                xy, x, y;

            if (!me.sprite) {
                xy = surface.getEventXY(e);
                x = xy[0];
                y = xy[1];

                me.list = [x, y, x, y];
                me.lastEventX = x;
                me.lastEventY = y;

                me.sprite = surface.add({
                    type: 'path',
                    path: ['M', me.list[0], me.list[1], 'L', me.list[0] + 1e-1, me.list[1] + 1e-1],
                    lineWidth: 20,
                    lineCap: 'round',
                    lineJoin: 'round',
                    strokeStyle: new Ext.util.Color(0,0,0)
                });
                surface.renderFrame();
            }
        },

        onMouseMove: function (e) {
            var targetElement = this,
                me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id),
                surface = me.getSurface(),
                path, xy, x, y, dx, dy, D;

            if (me.sprite) {
                xy = surface.getEventXY(e);
                x = xy[0];
                y = xy[1];
                dx = me.lastEventX - x;
                dy = me.lastEventY - y;
                D = 10;

                if (dx * dx + dy * dy < D * D) {
                    me.list.length -= 2;
                    me.list.push(x, y);
                } else {
                    me.list.length -= 2;
                    me.list.push(me.lastEventX = x, me.lastEventY = y);
                    me.list.push(me.lastEventX + 1, me.lastEventY + 1);
                }

                path = smoothList(me.list);

                me.sprite.setAttributes({
                    path: path
                });
                if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
                    Ext.draw.Animator.schedule(function () {
                        surface.renderFrame();
                    }, me);
                } else {
                    surface.renderFrame();
                }
            }
        },

        onMouseUp: function(e) {
            var targetElement = this,
                me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id);

            me.sprite = null;
        },

        onResize: function() {
            var size = this.element.getSize();

            this.getSurface().setRect([0, 0, size.width, size.height]);
            this.renderFrame();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you please let me know which version you using? and also please explain this `be able to select and copy the sprite`

Comment: @Njdhv sencha ext-6.5.2

Comment: @Njdhv I want to be able to move the drawing around and copy and paste it

Comment: it means whatever you have drawn you want to move/copy/paste on canvas ?

Comment: @Njdhv yes is it possible?

Comment: I don't know but lets try :)

Comment: @Njdhv if drawing does not work can it be shapes? thank you for your help having a hard time learning ext js very complicated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162476/discussion-between-njdhv-and-pat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `width` and `colour` you can use [`ComboBox`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) and [`ColorPicker`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.picker.Color.html).

In this **[FIDDlE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bfj)**, I have created a demo using your code and put some modification in your code. I hope this will help you or guide you for achieve your requirement. For `copy` and `paste` still I am working If I will get success then I will update my answer here.

```
function smoothList(points) {
    if (points.length < 3) {
        return ['M', points[0], points[1]];
    }

    var dx = [],
        dy = [],
        result = ['M'],
        i, ln = points.length;

    for (i = 0; i < ln; i += 2) {
        dx.push(points[i]);
        dy.push(points[i + 1]);
    }

    dx = Ext.draw.Draw.spline(dx);
    dy = Ext.draw.Draw.spline(dy);
    result.push(dx[0], dy[0], 'C');

    for (i = 1, ln = dx.length; i < ln; i++) {
        result.push(dx[i], dy[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

Ext.define('ShapesDrawComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.draw.Component',
    alias: 'widget.free-draw-component',
    config: {
        background: 'white',
        strokeStyle: '000000',
        lineWidth: 5
    },

    sprite: undefined,
    lastEventX: undefined,
    lastEventY: undefined,
    list: [],

    constructor: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on({
            element: 'element',
            mousedown: 'onMouseDown',
            mousemove: 'onMouseMove',
            mouseup: 'onMouseUp',
            mouseleave: 'onMouseUp',
            scope: me
        });
    },

    onMouseDown: function (e) {
        var targetElement = this,
            me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id),
            surface = me.getSurface(),
            xy, x, y;

        if (!me.sprite) {
            xy = surface.getEventXY(e);
            x = xy[0];
            y = xy[1];

            me.list = [x, y, x, y];
            me.lastEventX = x;
            me.lastEventY = y;

            me.sprite = surface.add({
                type: 'path',
                path: ['M', me.list[0], me.list[1], 'L', me.list[0] + 1e-1, me.list[1] + 1e-1],
                lineWidth: me.getLineWidth(),
                lineCap: 'round',
                lineJoin: 'round',
                strokeStyle: `#${me.getStrokeStyle()}`
            });
            surface.renderFrame();
        }
    },

    onMouseMove: function (e) {
        var targetElement = this,
            me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id),
            surface = me.getSurface(),
            path, xy, x, y, dx, dy, D;

        if (me.sprite) {
            xy = surface.getEventXY(e);
            x = xy[0];
            y = xy[1];
            dx = me.lastEventX - x;
            dy = me.lastEventY - y;
            D = 10;

            if (dx * dx + dy * dy < D * D) {
                me.list.length -= 2;
                me.list.push(x, y);
            } else {
                me.list.length -= 2;
                me.list.push(me.lastEventX = x, me.lastEventY = y);
                me.list.push(me.lastEventX + 1, me.lastEventY + 1);
            }

            path = smoothList(me.list);

            me.sprite.setAttributes({
                path: path
            });
            if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
                Ext.draw.Animator.schedule(function () {
                    surface.renderFrame();
                }, me);
            } else {
                surface.renderFrame();
            }
        }
    },

    onMouseUp: function (e) {
        var targetElement = this,
            me = Ext.getCmp(targetElement.id);

        me.sprite = null;
    },

    onResize: function () {
        var size = this.element.getSize();

        this.getSurface().setRect([0, 0, size.width, size.height]);
        this.renderFrame();
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'anchor',
    itemId: 'mypanel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.draw.Component',
        'ShapesDrawComponent'
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: {
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderStyle: 'solid'
    },

    tbar: ['->', {
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Choose width',
        emptyText: 'Select Width',
        store: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        value: 5,
        listeners: {
            select: function (combo) {
                this.up('#mypanel').down('free-draw-component').setLineWidth(combo.getValue());
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Choose a color',
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            items: [{
                text: 'Choose a color',
                xtype: 'colorpicker',
                value: "000000",
                listeners: {
                    select: function (picker, color) {
                        this.up('#mypanel').down('free-draw-component').setStrokeStyle(color);
                        this.up('button').blur();
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Clear',
        handler: function () {
            // Remove all the sprites and redraw.
            var draw = Ext.getCmp('free-draw');
            draw.getSurface().removeAll(true);
            draw.renderFrame();
        }
    }],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'free-draw-component',
        id: 'free-draw',
        anchor: '100%',
        height: window.innerHeight
    }],

    onAdded: function (container, pos, instanced) {
        this.callParent([container, pos, instanced]);
        container.setScrollable(false);
    },

    onRemoved: function (destroying) {
        this.ownerCt.setScrollable(true);
        this.callParent([destroying]);
    }
});
```

For `copy` and `paste` here is link as I have searched hope this will help you [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/7Hsdh/1/).